# Mysql Query to retrieve data based on values length

Tags: mysql

Hii Guys!!!
             i have a table named cdrcost which has dst column.I am need to retrieve the values based on digits in the column values.
For example:

dst

0001266
2545
874545565612
25452`

Any suggestion will be welcomed

Comment: The first suggestion - read your question once again and say honestly: do you really think it's possible to get what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you're asking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cdrcost 
WHERE LENGTH(dst) = 31;
```